# How to chose one employee of two working the same month same position

Tags: sql, min

I have an HR table H with information about employees and a period table with dates and all periods(months). I may have a situation when one person. I'm joining them because I need to have information about every month(for other tasks). But I may have situation when one person(A) leaves in the middle of the month, B person starts his position in the middle of the same month. In this case for the current month I have to consider that person A is working on this position.
Could you please help me to do it?
Thank you very much in advance!

```
    SELECT 
           ,H.[PERSON_ID]
           ,H.[TITLE]
           ,H.[START_DATE]
           ,H.[END_DATE]
           ,IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) as ED
           ,H.[DESCRIPTION]
           ,Per.PeriodID
           ,Per.CalDateStart
           ,Per.CalDateEnd
 
         FROM H
                 inner join Period Per
                        on IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) >= Per.CalDateStart
                        and H.START_DATE <= Cast(Per.CalDateEnd as date)
    Where 1 = 1
   and PERSON_ID in (73, 81)
```

Comment: Pls provide sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To solve the problem:**

1. Change the JOIN condition. If the employee's employment period encloses the `Per.CalDateStart` of one period, safely consider the employee was working during that period.

```sql
on IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) >= Per.CalDateStart
   and H.START_DATE <= Per.CalDateStart
```

**To further optimize:**

1. Use RIGHT JOIN to retain every single period in your Per table, making sure that we "have information about *every month* for the other tasks".
2. Use ORDER BY to sort the periods, for two benefits:

   1. The result is in a clear chronicle order.
   2. If one period is falsely binded with two or more employees, making it standout visually, and easy to detect programmatically.

```sql
SELECT 
       ,H.[PERSON_ID]
       -- unchanged snippet --
FROM H
       right join Period Per
       on IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) >= Per.CalDateStart
          and H.START_DATE <= Per.CalDateStart
Where 1 = 1
      and PERSON_ID in (73, 81)
ORDER BY Per.CalDateStart
```

-- Content below was appended on 2022-08-24 --

**To aggregate, making one period binded with at most one empolyee:**

1. Use GROUP BY to aggregate the rows of the same period (with identical `Per.PeriodID`) into just *one row*. This *one row* shall be the row that has, saying, the earliest `H.[START_DATE]`.

   1. Your business logic in practice defines the actual aggregation condition to apply.

```sql
SELECT 
       ,H.[PERSON_ID]
       ,H.[TITLE]
       ,MIN(H.[START_DATE])  -- aggregation condition
       -- unchanged snippet --
      and PERSON_ID in (73, 81)
GROUP BY Per.PeriodID  -- aggregation
ORDER BY Per.CalDateStart
```

**(Optional) To exclude the rows that have no empolyee binded:**

1. Based on the total number of binded employees, add HAVING condition in the aggregation.

```sql
-- unchanged snippet --
GROUP BY Per.PeriodID
HAVING COUNT(H.[PERSON_ID]) > 0
ORDER BY Per.CalDateStart
```

-- Content below was appended on 2022-08-25 --

**To summarize:**

```sql
SELECT 
       ,H.[PERSON_ID]
       ,H.[TITLE]
       ,MIN(H.[START_DATE])
       ,H.[END_DATE]
       ,IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) as ED
       ,H.[DESCRIPTION]
       ,Per.PeriodID
       ,Per.CalDateStart
       ,Per.CalDateEnd
FROM H
       right join Period Per
       on IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) >= Per.CalDateStart
          and H.START_DATE <= Per.CalDateStart
Where 1 = 1
      and PERSON_ID in (73, 81)
GROUP BY Per.PeriodID
HAVING COUNT(H.[PERSON_ID]) > 0
ORDER BY Per.CalDateStart
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how can I solve this problem: "If one period is falsely binded with two or more employees, making it standout visually, and easy to detect programmatically" ? That's my biggest issue. Could you please help me with it?  I have a lot of employees(person_id), 73 and 81 are just two examples for testing purposes.

Comment: please see above

Comment: Cheers! The multi-binded issue can be addressed by using aggregation. See the edited anwser.

Comment: Thank you so much! @zhugen Should we add min(H.START_DATE)  to this condition?  H.START_DATE <= Per.CalDateStart. Should we use min(H.START_DATE) somewhere else? In group by we should add all this columns (H.[PERSON_ID]
           ,H.[TITLE]
           ,H.[START_DATE]
           ,H.[END_DATE]
           ,IsNUll(H.END_DATE, Cast(getdate() as date)) as ED
           ,H.[DESCRIPTION]
           ,Per.PeriodID
           ,Per.CalDateStart
           ,Per.CalDateEnd), shouldn't we?

Comment: Sure! The `H.START_DATE <= Per.CalDateStart` condition remains to be one of the two RIGHT JOIN conditions, though `min(H.START_DATE)` should only exsit as the aggregation condition, as `min()` is the function meant solely for aggregation. All those columns you mentioned still remains in the SELECT section. The `-- unchanged snippet --` represents the code unchanged as the previous code. Without the `-- unchanged snippet --`, the redundant code will make my post lengthy.

Comment: These steps in my post were to sort out the problem gradually. For clarity, I updated my anwser to include the finalized code.